# Running docker-compose from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I am looking for a way to run a docker-compose file from python script. I looked in Docker SDK for python, but i didn't found anything about docker-compose.
So, is there a way to run a docker-compose file from python script?

Comment: `docker-compose` **is** a Python script :)

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/cli/main.py#L182

Comment: ah! i didn't know that, but maybe I am not very clear about what I want to do. Let say I have a flask application, I also have some docker-compose scripts, and I want to execute them from my application. Isn't there someway to do that?

Comment: It's not a supported use case, nor meant to be used that way. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4542#issuecomment-283191533  You could just use `subprocess` module to shell out to the commands, or use `docker-py` directly

Comment: Ok so, I think the simplest way for me is to use subprocess module. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: docker run is not the same as docker-compose - it's two different projects that are only marginally linked. Please reopen the question.

Comment: I voted to open this because the linked answer does not specify how to run `docker-compose`, only `docker`.

Answer (score 8):

The question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697261/running-docker-compose-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment94250034_53697261) by @cricket_007:

> It's not a supported use case, nor meant to be used that way. github.com/docker/compose/issues/4542#issuecomment-283191533 You could just use subprocess module to shell out to the commands, or use docker-py directly – cricket_007 Dec 9 '18 at 22:36

And the answer was [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697261/running-docker-compose-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment94250132_53697261) by the OP:

> Ok so, I think the simplest way for me is to use subprocess module. Thanks for your response :) – Nidal

Comment: This was answered as a community wiki entry, in the spirit of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins.  This looks a proper answer for a proper question.  If the actual author of the answer put an actual answer, I can remove this one.  I just want it to get out of my search results :)

Comment: This does not the answer directly. How to actually get it done? This does not say.

Comment: @Gulzar, the answer is: If you want to use docker-compose from Python, you'll have to call it as any other executable, using `subprocess`.  Why: docker-compose is not supposed to be used as a library (see link).

Comment: Was looking for actual code that does that. I wrote it myself already.